# How to change custom logo size of theme in nopcommerce 3.70

Tags: css, nopcommerce

I want to change the size of custom logo in nopfashion theme in nopcommerce 3.70.

I want `width: 205px; height:height:90px;` and `margin-top:-35px;` of logo.

I have tried to give this property to the logo related css class and its working also. But the issue is that at the same time other images also getting this css effect.

So, just I want to know that in nopcommerce is there any private css class was there which property was effect in logo only not other images.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the parent have a unique id/class/selector?

Comment: I don't think so. Because whatever the class has been showing in this logo [in console tool] other images also effected. like jcarosel image, ajax image.

Comment: Never used Nopcommerce before so trying my best to help :). You can maybe target it by children?